# woocommerce banner on front page. How to remove?

Tags: woocommerce, banner

[My site:](https://www.pandaspencer.com)

When I was setting up the store I was prompted to create a banner.  I thought, gee that looks great, wonder if I will be able to remove it....
Well, I cannot seem to find where to remove the banner.  It is only on the home page and only when you first load.

Thanks!

Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the banner by logging into your Wordpress backend and doing the following steps:

1. Open Appearance > Customizer
2. Open the Woocommerce tab
3. Click on Store notice
4. Disable the store notice by removing the check in the checkbox.